# How can I add a glow effect around a pair of wings in Unity without post processing?

Tags: unity, shaders

Basically I want to use post processing and then I found a [tutorial](https://willweissman.wordpress.com/tutorials/shaders/unity-shaderlab-object-outlines/) to achieve my goal. However, the artist want a pure shader to achieve this, without any C# script hanging in the main camera. Any idea to implement?

Comment: It would help if you can show us your source asset and desired end effect (using your post processing technique), so we can try to match that target as best we can without post-processing.

Comment: That tutorial shows the effect I did. Now I'm trying to do that without post-processing.

Comment: I've already seen the tutorial you linked. I asked to see the effect on  *your* assets, because that truly does make a difference to the kinds of answers we give you.

Comment: I can't upload my assets based on my company's policy, sorry for that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't normally would do something like this with post processing, as post processing is only able to render the whole scene. But you want a specific object/objects to be rendered with a glowing shader.

This would normally only work with C#, but Unity lately updated the engine and added a Graph Shader Editor.

Here's a tutorial that goes into the direction in what you try to achieve:

[Click](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qTYOWRWuBQg)

EDIT:

Like mentioned in my comment, you either update to Unity2018, which is something i would definitely do, considering all the new features that are coming with it. Migration works just fine, just make sure to have a copy of your original project.

It comes with the Graph Shader Editor, ProBuilder and much more. The only way to achieve a outside glowing is by using a shader that calculates the outside and make it appear to glow. If you want certain parts to be emissive inside your mesh (for example a panel with a monitor and you want to add a glowing effect to the monitor) you need to cut out these parts for the UV map and drop them inside the emission input. This way you will have full control over this area and can literally do almost anything, from special shaders to simple emission effects. Read more about emission [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html)

If you want the glowing effect around a character/object, you have to do it by either buying a shader or making one by yourself, which isnt that hard with the new Graph Editor.

GreetingS!

Comment: OP, did you downvote both posts? If so, would you like to explain why?

Comment: I didn't do that. But my project is using unity 2017 and there is no Graph Shader Editor, I'm curious how to use pure shader to achieve my goal.

Comment: Also, wings are not like sphere. I did rim light for the wings but it's totally not working because of normals.

Comment: There is no way in doing that without C#. Try to use Unity2018, you can easily migrate your project, lots of benefits beside the Graph Editor. The only way that is left is that you have to UV map your object on yourself and map out the areas you want to later to glow. Then, with the extra UV map you have to drop it inside the emission part on your shader and change the value there. But again, this is very hacky and that is why there are shaders. If you don't have any static emission, using the shader is always the better option.

Comment: I can't decide which version of Unity I am using...

Comment: Its not clear what you really want to do, heres is the thumb rule for the two possible scenerios: When want certain parts inside your mesh to be glowing, you need the uv map for this parts and connect them to the emission input. This will give you full control over the emission (glowing), and even make it possible to render shader stuff onto this cutted out areas. If you simply want an all glowing effect, like shown in the blog post, you need to use a shader that calculates the outside of your mesh and makes it appear to be glowing. There are no other ways than those two. Greetings!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with an edge shader, if you google about you will find some code for sure. If you are in Unity2018 you can use shader graph editor if you are afraid of coding shader code.

Comment: the wings have no thickness, normal edge shader doesn't work.

Comment: Telling users "to google some code" is not as good as posting the actual code that would help the user.